# I want to compare the values of the index in a list, but one index doesn't exist, how can I hanlde that error

Tags: python, indexing

I need to create a new list with other 2 lists by comparing each element in both list first; deleting the smallest value; adding the other to the new list.

But the 2 lists are not the same length so in one point it will compare between an index and nothing but I don't know how to handle this.

```
lista1=[1,3,2,4]
lista2=[0,2,3,4,5]
listaN=[]

for i in range (0,11):
    if lista1[0]<lista2[0]:
        listaN.append(lista1[0])
        lista1.pop(0)
        print("Lista1 =",lista1)
        print("Lista2 =",lista2)
        print(listaN)
        print("")          

    else:
        listaN.append(lista2[0])
        lista2.pop(0) 
        print("Lista1 else =",lista1)
        print("Lista2 else =",lista2) 
        print("ListaN else =",listaN)
        print("")

print(listaN)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a wealth of knowledge on this site, and most likely someone has asked your question before. Have you researched online how to handle Python errors, compare lists of different length, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shortcut:

```
listaN=lista1+lista2
listaN.sort()
```

or:

```
while lista1 and lista2: #runs while there are elements in both lists
    if lista1[0]<lista2[0]:
        listaN.append(lista1[0])
        lista1.pop(0)
        print("Lista1 =",lista1)
        print("Lista2 =",lista2)
        print(listaN)
        print("")          

    else:
        listaN.append(lista2[0])
        lista2.pop(0) 
        print("Lista1 else =",lista1)
        print("Lista2 else =",lista2) 
        print("ListaN else =",listaN)
        print("")

#or add another for in the ifs if you need all the prints:
if lista1:
     lista1.sort()
if lista2:
     lista2.sort()    
listaN=listaN+lista1+lista2
```